# c# SendMessage to button without handle

Tags: c#, sendmessage

This is the similar topic, but can't get it to work.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/21cc58c5-fc34-45b0-9407-952aae80fc1c/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouse-click-in-an-inactive-window?forum=vbinterop

I want to send click to a button without handle.  Spy++ shows it does not have a handle.  I can get it to work with these code, but it has to be an active window and only using screen position instead of control handle position.   I want to send it to an inactive window with a child control with no windows handle. like minimized window within a position in a TPanel.

```
    public static void ClickLeftMouseButton(int x, int y)
    {
        var oldPos = Cursor.Position;

        INPUT mouseInput = new INPUT();
        mouseInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dx = CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateX(x);
        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dy = CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateY(y);
        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.mouseData = 0;


        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        /// return mouse 
        Cursor.Position = oldPos;
    }
```

I am having trouble with SendMessage() or PostMessage.

First question is with SendMessage or PostMessage.

static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

The mouse position for IParam, is it relative to the screen or to the handle control.

Let's say the button does not have a handle, but i want to use the parent handle and get the relative position to the parent (TPanel) and initialize that click.. Does it click?

The link from above did show a handle, but where does that handle from? is it the whole gui window handle or the parent of that non-handle button.  Like a TPanel?

the position is another question.  If the PostMessage is based on a handle.  Is the position from that top left position of the handle or top left of the screen?

let's say the screen ranges from 0,0 to 100,100.  The handle from PostMessage is 10,10 to 20, 20.  can it be possible to initialize a click outside the scope of the position of the handle?

Thanks

Comment: If a control has no handle, then probably it's an WPF app. In WPF apps, there is usually only one handle available: the handle of the window. The WPF controls are not Win32 controls and thus don't need any handles. If you can confirm that you're trying to push a button in a WPF app, then there are much easier ways to do that, e.g. using UI Automation.

Comment: I am more the same of using ui automation, is there any ui automation to look at controls in wpf.  Isn't the bottom line is, it still needs a handle for ui automation to control it? I am using spy++ to look.  It does list all programs control.   I think it is more like a image button than buttons.. there are buttons in the program  it is just that specific ones doesn't have control.  Under tpanel.  It has other elements controls but does have that specific button.